# confusion about getting an element from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajax expression that gets information from a URL and the success function is supposed to output the first element in an array so I quickly made a function that does this:

```
success: function(data) {
            console.log(data[1]);
            $('<div id="allResults">'+ alert(data[1].get[0]) +'</div>').appendTo('#results').html();

        }
```

but for some reason `.get[0]` is an undefined property.. I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`..

the `console.log` outputs this:

`["The Killers", "The Beatles", "The Kinks", "The Orb", "The Wire", "The Simpsons", "Thoroughbred", "The Raven", "Thylacine", "Thor"]`

and I'm not sure how I can get the first element... Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `data[0][0]`. It looks like a double dimension array to me

Comment: What is .get[] ? What you are trying to achieve can done by data[1][1] .

Comment: you are logging out 2nd element of data by `data[1]` which consists of `["The Killers", "The Beatles", "The Kinks", "The Orb", "The Wire", "The Simpsons", "Thoroughbred", "The Raven", "Thylacine", "Thor"]` where as you are trying to get data from 1st element of data by `data[0]`, can you tell us what is the output if you log `data[0]`

Comment: @roshan, you're right. That worked. It's tired and I'm late... Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in JavaScript haven't got native method `get`, therefore you get error. To achieve double dimension use `data[0][1]`